# Newly installed kernel version missing from GRUB menu

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I have a problem with dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my computer. When I chose Ubuntu, another option appears that lets me choose a kernel version. However, the kernel I just installed is not on this list.

Version in the list: 3.5.2
Updated installed version: 3.5.3

Comment: I translated your question into English.

Comment: Para solução o problema usei seguinte comandos: `sudo apt-get update
sudo && apt-get install grub-pc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably not updated GRUB after installing your new kernel. Try running:

```
$ update-grub
$ grub-install /dev/sda
```

Replace "sda" with the appropriate disk if grub is not installed on the MBR of your first hard drive.